# Trigger on insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have one table `CLIENT` where `CLIENT_ID`, a varchar, is the primary key. The first character of CLIENT_ID must start with a "C" when inserting into this table.

A Check Constraint is not working properly, so I would like to use a trigger.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of using C as initial, can you using two column, CLIENT_INITIAL, CLIENT_ID, and set as primary key?

Comment: thanx for ur reply... but i don't want any extra columns, that id initial character start with "C".. just like C1, C2, C3 and more..

Comment: @ajreal if `client_initial` would always start with a "C" it's a pretty pointless column.

Comment: No, I did not say must set it to C. You should ask OP, what is the point to fix a initial C...

Comment: Use a trigger... how? To constrain? To prepend? To what? You haven't stated your product requirements to anywhere near enough detail, and this is also not a "gimmeh teh codez" site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're right, you could [Emulate a Check Constraint with trigger](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints) on MySQL 5.0.2+